# Can't get Adafruit Neopixel to work with Wemos D1

Tags: esp8266, led, neopixel

I am trying to get a very simple ESP8266 project to work but I keep failing and have no clue why.

These are my components:

- Wemos D1 (ESP8266MOD)
- WS2812B 5050 LED Stripe (2m with 60 LEDs/m)
- 5V 10A DC Power Supply

This is how I connected everything (I also tried multiple other pins on the controller)

[image]

Then I uploaded this code to the controller:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#define PIN            D2
#define NUMPIXELS      20
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
int delayval = 500;
void setup() {
  pixels.begin();
}
void loop() {
  pixels.clear();
  for(int i=0;i<NUMPIXELS;i++){
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0,150,0));
    pixels.show();
    delay(delayval);
  }
}
```

Absolutely nothing happens. The LEDs remain dark.
I measured the voltage directly on the strip connectors and it's fine. I've got no oszilloscope, but I get varying voltages on the ESPs data pin, so I suppose that's also working as expected.

I also stumbled upon this [article](https://www.robmiles.com/journal/2022/5/2/why-your-neopixels-might-not-work) stating that the signal voltage has to be at least 60% of the voltage of the stripe while my controller works with 3.3V (seee [Datasheet](https://www.makershop.de/download/d1-wifi-esp8266-board.pdf)). So I thought this might be part of the problem and tried it again wiht another power supply providing araound 3.8V at max. 5A with the same result. I am running out of ideas. Maybe you have got some for me.

Comment: I’m assuming you’ve provided power to the ESP8266 as your diagram doesn’t show that. Are you sure you have the data line connected to the input on the strip rather than the output? The data line is directional. Your photo shows it hooked up backwards. DI would be input; the arrows show the direction data goes in.

Comment: Good point, I didn’t think of that. My strip came with pre-soldered connecting wires but I will still recheck.

Comment: No, seems like I connected it correctly!